# About an xpath in a xml

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the xml below that I've pasted [here](http://www.mizar.dk/XPath/Default.aspx) with this rule:

> /bookstore/book/price/text()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

When I submit the form, the prices are remarked.

Now I'm trying to do the same with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
  <SearchResponse xmlns="http://www.liberologico.com/dbsite/jolly-search">
    <GlobalFilter>
      <Filters>
        <Filters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="FilterSpecType">
          <Field>aptve_territorio</Field>
          <Value>
            <TreeValue>
              <Value>*</Value>
            </TreeValue>
          </Value>
        </Filters>
        <Filters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="FilterSpecType">
          <Field>full_text_search</Field>
          <Value>
            <SingleValue>*</SingleValue>
          </Value>
        </Filters>
        <Filters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="FilterSpecType">
          <Field>lang</Field>
          <Value>
            <SingleValue>it</SingleValue>
          </Value>
        </Filters>
      </Filters>
    </GlobalFilter>
 </SearchResponse>
```

and this rule:

```
/SearchResponse/GlobalFilter/Filters/Filters/Field/Value/Treevalue/Value/text()
```

I expected the site remarks the "*" but it doesn't.. why?

Javi

Comment: The namespaces on the `<Filters>` and `<SearchResponse>` tags might be throwing things off.

Comment: @MarcB, they aren't namespaces of the said elements, they're namespaces of attributes.

Comment: Oops, that was only about `Filters`. Yes, that may also add to the problem.

Comment: Ah yeah, true enough. I think I need to get new eyes installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Value` is not a child of `Field` (You have `Field/Value` there).

Comment: Yes, that's true but it's not working anyway..This is my new xpath: /SearchResponse/GlobalFilter/Filters/Filters/Value/Treevalue/Value/text()

Comment: First you didn't tell what exactly isn't working now. Second, read Marc's comment, you need to declare namespace in your xml and prefix each element name in xpath expression with its prefix.

Comment: Like `xmlns:j="http://www.liberologico.com/dbsite/jolly-search"` and `/j:SearchResponse/j:GlobalFilter…`

Comment: And if it works, make Marc add his comment as an answer and accept it :)

Comment: No, I said you didn't tell what's not working before you added the new xpression.

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head, but might you need 'TreeValue' instead of 'Treevalue'...

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is an XML default namespace involved (see the `xmlns="http://www.liberologico.com/dbsite/jolly-search"` declaration).

An XPath expression like `/SearchResponse` will match nothing since there actually is no element of that name (an element's namespace always counts into its name).

Unless you tell the server to look at elements specifically in this namespace, it will never find them.

You can work around this by either specifying that you're looking for elements in *any* namespace (the `local-name()` function extracts the plain element name):

```
//*[local-name() = 'Treevalue']/*/text()
```

or by telling the server that a namespace is involved, giving it a prefix (say, `js`) and issuing an XPath search for fully qualified names:

```
//js:Treevalue/*/text()
```

The first method is easy since there is no code change required on the server side. Then again it requires long-winded and ugly XPath expressions. The second method requires implementing namespace support on the server but XPath expressions will be nice and clean.

The third method would be to remove the namespace declaration from the XML before you send it to the server, but – depending on your situation – that might not be feasible.